# Use different connectionString in production environment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, environment-variables, appsettings

i am new to Web-Development and so it is the first time, that I try to work with different environments.

So in my WebApp which is deployed on Azure I want to use a connectionString for my local database, when I am working locally in development environment, and when I deploy it, it should use a different database with another connectionString.

I have seen that there are two files in my Asp.Net Core project. "appsettings.json" and "appsettings.Development.json". If I understand correctly, app.dev.json should override the settings in app.json if I work in Development Environment. But it doesn`t. When I am debugging the app, to realy make sure that environment is set to development, it still uses appsettings.json.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be correct in term of `Multiple Configuration Files`. `appsettings.json` is a default configuration file that you can declare anything which includes both `Development` and `Production`. The merging pattern will be `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, then **all matching keys will replace all keys in appsettings.json**. Remembered the name `Environment` should be matched with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to be used. In you case, `app.dev.json` so your environment should be `dev` (case-sensitive) instead of `Development`.

For example: We have a default `appsettings.json

```json
{
    "ConfigurationString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "MongoOptions": {
        "AllowWireUp": true,
        "AutoConnect": true
    }
}
```

Then you want to work in `Development`, you create `appsettings.Development.json` with content

```json
{
    "ConfigurationString": "mongodb://192.168.1.1:27017",
    "MongoOptions": {
        "AllowWireUp": false
    }
}
```

Later when you run with `Development`, you will get combined file

```json
{
    "ConfigurationString": "mongodb://192.168.1.1:27017",
    "MongoOptions": {
        "AllowWireUp": false
    }
}
```

**Important**: You will see `MongoOptions.AutoConnect` is `false` in `Development` because .NET Core merges two files based on first level key instead of merging nested. That means `MongoOptions` in `appsettings.Development.json` will replace entire your `appsettings.json`

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to find my problem. There have just been problems with the brackets, therefore it didn`t merge

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that. I guess you are using Azure app service?. if so follow thease steps

1. Create multiple app-settings files inside your project. (dev/ staging / uat / prod)
2. These file names shoud be **appsettings.Development.json**  **appsettings.uat.json** and **appsettings.Production.json**
3. Each file should contain its own configurations.
4. Then Go to your App service in azure > configuration > Application settings , add required prifix of your appsettings json file in Value filed in **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**
5. Restart app service. it should work now

[image]